# HTML table is cut when printed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to print a HTML table that I styled with Bootstrap and custom CSS to a PDF but the table is always cut after the first page which leads to rows that should appear on the second page disappearing. A second page isn't even printed.

The CSS of the table (apart from the default Bootstrap CSS):

```
#report-table {
    width: 100%
}

#report-table thead,
#report-table tbody,
#report-table tr,
#report-table td,
#report-table th{
    display: block;
}

#report-table tr:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
}

#report-table thead th {
    height: 30px;
}

#report-table tbody{
    height: 325px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#report-table tbody td,
#report-table thead th {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

#report-table table {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
@media print {
    #report-table tbody {
        height: 100% !important;
    }
    #report-table table {
        margin-bottom: auto !important;
    }
}
```

The html of the table:

```
<table class="table table-striped"><thead><tr><th>Activity</th> <th>Duration</th></tr></thead> <tbody><tr><td>yay</td> <td>
                            00:00:01
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:02
                        </td></tr><tr><td>y</td> <td>
                            00:00:00
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:00
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:00
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:00
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:00
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:00
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:00
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:00
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:00
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:00
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:00
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:00
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:00
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:00
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:00
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:00
                        </td></tr><tr><td>ay</td> <td>
                            00:00:01
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:01
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:00
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:00
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:00
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:01
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:01
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:01
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:01
                        </td></tr><tr><td></td> <td>
                            00:00:01
                        </td></tr><tr><td>end</td> <td>
                            00:00:03
                        </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

This is the only page of the result (ignore the other content apart from the table):

[image]

Comment: The `tbody` has `overflow-y: hidden` and `height:100%` so it won't be larger than a single page.

Comment: @pawel Thank you for your answer. I tried setting `height: auto !important; overflow-y: auto !important;` but that didn't work. Was that what you meant?